# Kibana filter regex 'string starts with' doesn't work

Tags: kibana, elastic-stack

In Kibana chart I want to filter all urls that start with string `CANCELLED` so I wrote a regex: `^CANCELLED.*` but when I use filter in Discover tab then I notice that filter doesn't work properly because it also accepts urls with phrase `CANCELLED` inside of an url.

Is it because Kibana regex uses other character than caret for the beginning of a string?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of filters you should use the search textfield at the top of the webpage because filters don't fully support regex, after a chart is saved search queries will be also saved. As the wildcard use `*` instead of `.*`. That's how your search query should look like:

```
url.keyword:CANCELLED*
```